# is it right to use dapper and MongoDb in one application

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, best-fit

I'm developing BPM (business process management system) in asp.net C# and workflow foundation 4.5.

bpm systems usually have allot of process and each process has many forms. i made that easy by using JSON data so i will store all forms data in one table, so there is no need to create many tables for each process but this approach will effect the process searching service (advanced search for process business intelligence and business analysis ), 
so im thinking to use MongoDb to store that Forms' data and search in it. is that will be a good approach and practice?

another question
is using windows workflow foundation will be a good idea, i didn't see a lot of systems using it lately

Comment: Dapper + MongoDB in one application. I've same question now. no one replied. Are you doing in one application. Up-course we can do it in one application. Does it correct way ?

Comment: I was trying to use mongodb in an application wich has unlimeted forms so i didnt want to create for each form many tables to store the data so i thought i can use mongodb for that. And sql db i was going to use it for application configuration  and settings. @kanaparthi

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that's a no.  Dapper is meant to be a wrapper for ADO.NET.

https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/671